# how to move fs resource in service group in ccs cluster

Tags: rhel, cluster

I have a ccs cluster running on RHEL 6.4 where there is no luci service, i have added a filesystem resource to the cluster with the below command but i need to move the resource inside a service group....but couldn't find any specific command/switch for this apart from manually editing the cluster.conf file. Kindly guide!

```
ccs -h DBPNODE --addresource fs name=FS_ORACLE device=/dev/mapper/VG_LV mountpoint=/oracle fstype=ext4 force_unmount=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't anticipate it to be known as subservice, somehow fumbled onto it.
To add resource to service group:

> ccs -h hostname --addsubservice SG_name fs ref=FS_name

To sync the updated configuration across cluster nodes:

> ccs -h hostname --sync

Source: `https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/ha_web_server_on_rhel_6.pdf`